# Access Jinja2 dict_keys values inside templete

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to figure out why in Jinja2 the following code does not work. I am setting the keys of a dictionary inside Jinja2 this dictionary has only one key and I want to access the key name however calling the `tc_class_name` variable inside Jinja2 only returns the following `dict_keys(['TestEVPNSingleFlow']))` I have tried to use list index `{{tc_class_name[0]})` but some reason that returns nothing. However I tried doing that in Python and using list index works. Also if I do a Jinja2 for loop over `tc_class_name` that does work but would prefer a better solution because I will run into other issues if I use a Jinja2 for loop

**Jinja2 code**

```
{% set tc_class_name = chart_data[0]['TestCaseData'].keys() %}
{{tc_class_name})

# returning the following when i print out tc_class_name variable inside the HTML
# dict_keys(['TestEVPNSingleFlow']))
```

**Normal Python code**

```
In [17]: tc_class_name = chart_data[0]['TestCaseData'].keys()

# This is what I am trying to do via Jinja2 not sure why this is not working for Jinja
In [19]: tc_class_name[0]
Out[19]: 'TestEVPNSingleFlow'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So as I figured the solution was quite easy just needed to return the `dict_keys` as a true `list` for jinja2 to understand. Below is what I ended up doing.

```
{% set tc_class_name = chart_data[list_len]['TestCaseData'].keys() | list %}
```